# Sheet.Select + Copy/Paste won't work [Excel 2016]

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that copies some columns from a BD Sheet and pastes in another sheet.

I've got this code working in Excel 2007, but I've encountered an issue Selecting a Sheet, then copy/paste in Excel 2010 and later. It seems the problem is not in my `.Select`. It appears to be in the `PasteSpecial()` that automatically selects the `with Sheet()` and executes other `.copy()` without going back to de previous sheet (the screen blinks every `pasteSpecial`) - I don't know if I was clear enough. [sometimes it works fine, especially using debugger]

**Code**

```
Const BD_SHEET As String = "Estrategia"
Const PRICE_SHEET As String = "Precos"

Public Sub Execute()
    ....

    actualCalculate = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    LoadPrices()

    Application.Calculate
    Application.Calculation = actualCalculate
End Sub


Private Sub LoadPrices()
    Dim lastSheet As Worksheet

    Set lastSheet = ActiveSheet
    Sheets(BD_SHEET).Select
    lastRow = [A1000000].End(xlUp).row

    With Sheets(PRICE_SHEET)
        Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2)).Copy
        .[A2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  '<---- Working

        Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastRow, 7)).Copy
        .[B2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  '<---- Working

        Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(lastRow, 10)).Copy '<---- Error!
        .[C2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(lastRow, 12)).Copy '<---- Error!
        .[E2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    lastSheet.Select
End Sub
```

I can remove `.Select` and add `Set theSheet = Sheets(BD_SHEET)` but the code is going to be durty.

Exemple:

```
...
Set lastSheet = ActiveSheet
Set bdSheet = Sheets(BD_SHEET)
lastRow = [A1000000].End(xlUp).row

With Sheets(PRICE_SHEET)
    bdSheet.Range(bdSheet.Cells(2, 2), bdSheet.Cells(lastRow, 2)).Copy
    .[A2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`but the code is going to be durty.`

That is because you are doing it the wrong way

Instead of

```
With Sheets(PRICE_SHEET)
    bdSheet.Range(bdSheet.Cells(2, 2), bdSheet.Cells(lastRow, 2)).Copy
    .[A2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Do this

```
With bdSheet
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2)).Copy
    Sheets(PRICE_SHEET).[A2].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  '<---- Working
End With
```

Also never use Hardcoded values to find the last row. You may see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) on how to calculate the last row.

Also

```
Range1.Copy
Range2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

can be written as

```
Range2.Value = Range1.Value
```

Applying the above, I have re-written your code. Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Private Sub LoadPrices()
    Dim wsCopyFrm As Worksheet, wsCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wsCopyFrm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(BD_SHEET)
    Set wsCopyTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PRICE_SHEET)

    With wsCopyFrm
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2))
        wsCopyTo.Range("A2").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(lastRow, 7))
        wsCopyTo.Range("B2").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(lastRow, 10))
        wsCopyTo.Range("C2").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 12), .Cells(lastRow, 12))
        wsCopyTo.Range("E2").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    End With
End Sub
```